Add secure variable - react app - azure pipeline build
I have added variables in azure pipeline but its not attached in copy files in last step of copy
Below yml script:
trigger:
- branch name

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  projectFolder: '.'
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.17.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 14.17.0

- script: 'npm i'
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Constants.json'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*Constants.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(projectFolder)'

- script: 'npm run build'
  displayName: 'build app'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: build
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

how to add download file in build zip.

You need to modify the Yaml script so it includes the downloaded file in the build artifact.
Try this code:
trigger:
- branch name

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  projectFolder: '.'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.17.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 14.17.0

- script: 'npm i'
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Constants.json'
    
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/Constants.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(projectFolder)'

- script: 'npm run build'
  displayName: 'build app'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: build
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

# Include downloaded file in the build artifact
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Include Constants.json in Artifact'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(projectFolder)' # Source folder where Constants.json is located
    Contents: 'Constants.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'


I have added include cInclude Constants.json in Artifact in my pipeline still login is not working after deployment.

Login is not working ? I thought the issue was with the download

I found the issue. issue was in path. If i download file with another name but I want the name of constant.json in copy file. it is possible.

In your last CopyFiles@2 task, you copy files from build folder, which actually is $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build. So if you want Constants.json to be added to the .zip file, you need to copy it into $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build.
In the first CopyFiles@2 task, you copy Constants.json to $(projectFolder). I'm not sure about the actual value of $(projectFolder). According to the current information, it should be $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\build.
Try the scripts below and check if it helps.
trigger:
- branch name

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  projectFolder: 'build'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.17.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 14.17.0

- script: 'npm i'
  displayName: 'Install Dependencies'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Constants.json'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: 'Constants.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(projectFolder)'

- script: 'npm run build'
  displayName: 'build app'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: build
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

